# JavaFX Button EventHandler works one time(Card Shuffler)

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make a program that will display a random set of 4 cards, then when I click the button again it will clear the old set and display a new random set.

Right now my program will display 4 random images of cards when I click the button; however, when I try to click it again nothing happens. I'm assuming it has something to do with the `EventHandler` no longer being registered to the button after I clear the root children. However, I don't know how to go about fixing this. Any help is greatly appreciated! I haven't been able to find an answer to this yet, and have only been learning JavaFX for about a week. Thank you.

The code I have so far:

```
public class CardShuffle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File cardsFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\timsp\\Pictures\\JPEG");
        ArrayList<File> cardsFilePaths = new ArrayList<File> (Arrays.asList(cardsFolder.listFiles()));
        Button deal = new Button("DEAL");
        Pane hb = new HBox(10);
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        root.getChildren().add(deal);
        deal.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               root.getChildren().clear();
               ArrayList<ImageView> cards = getRandomCards(cardsFilePaths);
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    cards.get(i).setFitWidth(150);
                    cards.get(i).setFitHeight(100);
                    hb.getChildren().add(cards.get(i));
                }
                root.getChildren().addAll(deal, hb); 
           }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public ArrayList<ImageView> getRandomCards(ArrayList<File> cardsFilePaths) {
        ArrayList<ImageView> cards = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Image card = new Image((new FileInputStream(cardsFilePaths.get((int) (Math.random() * 52)).getPath())));
                ImageView temp = new ImageView();
                temp.setImage(card);
                cards.add(temp);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return cards;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many problems here :

the first one, and the most important (because it hides your further error) is the `root` layout : you use a StackPane, the first thing you should do is to replace it by a `VBox` for example and rerun your program, it will be easier to see what really happens. (you will not have 4 cards, but 8, 12, 16 and so on).

the first one generates the second one. By doing this `root.getChildren().addAll(deal, hb);` you put the `HBox` layout above the button, and the click is first consumed by the HBox. Here is an example to see it more easily :

```
// Add the HBox as soon as the initialization
root.getChildren().add(deal);
hb.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("HBox clicked"));
deal.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      root.getChildren().clear();
      ArrayList<ImageView> cards = getRandomCards(cardsFilePaths);
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         cards.get(i).setFitWidth(150);
         cards.get(i).setFitHeight(100);
         hb.getChildren().add(cards.get(i));
      }
      hb.setStyle("-fx-background-color:CORNFLOWERBLUE;-fx-opacity:0.8;");
      root.getChildren().addAll(deal, hb);
   }
});
```

And the last one, you don't really want to remove all `root`'s children, what you want is to replace your cards by another 4 ones. Thus it is not necessary to remove the `button`, only the `HBox` can be manipulated as shown by the following example :

```
// Add the HBox as soon as the initialization
root.getChildren().addAll(hb, deal);
deal.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      // root.getChildren().clear();
      // Replace the previous line by the following :
      hb.getChildren().clear();
      ArrayList<ImageView> cards = getRandomCards(cardsFilePaths);
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         cards.get(i).setFitWidth(150);
         cards.get(i).setFitHeight(100);
         hb.getChildren().add(cards.get(i));
      }
      // The following is useless now.
      // root.getChildren().addAll(hb, deal);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes so much sense now. That answers my question perfectly and you gave great examples of what my problems were. I eventually did get the program working, but still didn't realize what the problem was. I even asked my teacher about it today, and he kinda brushed me off and said yeah it's the button losing its functionality.

Comment: Ahah, sometimes teachers have no time to clarify the computing misteries ;). Do not hesitate to accept this answer if you think it can help people having a similar problem.